# mpdl3 and lmfit installations succesful from conda in the terminal but not found when imported in spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have installed **mpld3** and **lmfit** with **conda** in the anaconda terminal successfully and they exist in the packages folder of the **Anaconda3** folder.

When I try to import them through **spyder** the following message appears:

```
File "D:/Documents/covid/SIERD(t) modfit.py", line 15, in <module>
    import mpld3

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpld3'
```

Can somebody help me?

I am using spyder from **anaconda3** distribution installation in windows 10 64 bits.

Comment: Reviewing carefully the conda installation it result in a diuble instalattion so conda was installing on one installation while spyder was lokking on the second installation. I have unsitalled completely both installations and reinstalled anaconda and then install the modules succesfully and spyder can read them now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to know for sure without more info about your install.  Generally speaking, spaces in the name of the installation folder will cause many problems with Python installs. Having spaces, non-ASCII characters, or those parens in folder name is likely to cause trouble too.

Comment: C:\Users\Tt\Anaconda3\pkgs\mpld3-0.3-py37_0 and C:\Users\Tt\Anaconda3\pkgs\lmfit-1.0.0-py_0 are the paths of the packages. Maybe I should unistall them and try install them with pip.

Comment: Again (and sort of weird that it is not obvious), it is very hard to know what could be going wrong unless you tell us what you did.    Like, did you even install with `conda install`?  Yes, that is correct: we do not know that.  If you expect an answer to a question, you need to tell us what you did you did and what error messages you get.   But sure, start over and reinstall if that seems easier than explaining what you did in a way that anyone else would be able to understand and help you.